# How to print numbers in order using goroutine after emit all the goroutine

Tags: go, goroutine

How to print numbers in order using goroutine after all goroutines bing emited?

Here is the code which print numbers in random:

```
func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(10)
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            fmt.Printf("i = %d\n", i)
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
```

Emit goroutines in order to print numbers like below, it's not the solution I want.

```
func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            fmt.Printf("i = %d\n", i)
        }(i)
        wg.Wait()
    }
```

I want all goroutines being emited, and after then make them print numbers in order.

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense. You're asking to do something in parallel (thus go functions) but have their behavior be serial?

Comment: You could use goroutines to populate a slice in random order, then sort it and print it in the main thread. You could use a separate wait group or a blocking channel to cause all goroutines to block as soon as they're created, then lift the block after they're done so they all start at the same time, but that's no guarantee of order. Basically: do you want them to run in parallel, or do you want them to be in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```golang
func main() {
    wg.Add(10)
    count := 10
    cBegins := make([]chan interface{}, count)
    for i := range cBegins {
        cBegins[i] = make(chan interface{})
    }
    go func() {
        cBegins[0] <- struct {}{}
    }()
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            <-cBegins[i]
            fmt.Printf("i = %d\n", i)
            if i < 9 {
                cBegins[i+1] <- struct {}{}
            }
        }(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `runtime.Gosched()` which will print the previously declared goroutine. This works because `runtime.Gosched()` allows you to run other goroutines. At each iteration of the loop, there are only 2 goroutines: the main goroutine and the anonymous goroutine with `fmt.Printf`.

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            fmt.Printf("i = %d\n", i)
        }(i)
        runtime.Gosched()
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```